# how to learn operation like "add" via machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any idea?

Problem state:

```
Giving futures:
0+1=1, 1+1=2, 1+2=3, 1+3=4, 1+4=5,
1+5=6, 1+6=7, 1+7=8, 1+8=9, 1+9=10
How to build a machine learning algorithm to learn "+" operation in decimal?
```

e.g. after learning, 123+321 should get 444; 12345678901234567890+12 should get 12345678901234567902

The problem is hard for that **the size of data set is infinite**; traditional neural network method is good at classifying but requires enough training set, which is not proper for infinite set.

Although there are many ways to have a try to resolve the problem; but it cannot get good result on very large number. It means that algorithm like LSTM memories the mapping between operands and result, however it has not already learned how to do adding.

In addition, I mean using "Machine Learning" not restricted in "Neural Network".

(please read the ref before your answer; pure LSTM and similar algorithms are not powerful enough and they are not expected.)

Ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learn-add-numbers-seq2seq-recurrent-neural-networks/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest neural network will do just fine. Architecture:

- Input: equal to number of digits you want to add. In this case `2`.
- Output: single neuron with `bias=0` and `weight=1` for all input.
- Activation function: linear.

In general:

[image]

Given our architecture, your output will boils down to `sum(input)`, which is exactly the solution. Instead of fixing bias and weight you can let the system learn them, it will be very fast - just remember to use **linear activation**.

If you want to play fancy, you could use RNN. The trick would be to do this exactly as computers do: use binary representation. RNN should be able to learn how to carry the procedure. Why hurt yourself though?

Comment: thx for your answer. your method converts addition action into a classification action. in another word, the algorithm actually do read inputs of 2 numbers and classify the pair into output. however, if the size of number set is infinite, your method will fail. you cannot train a classifier with infinite set.

Comment: This is not a classification, but regression - you can see the formula yourself. Perhaps that's why you feel that for "infinite set" this will fail. Why sum(input), where input are arbitrary number, should fail? Also, to train it you don't need "infinite set", actually a small number of training examples will do. The algorithm needs only to learn two weights and bias, three numbers in total. Why do you want to train with "infinite set"? Strictly speaking, computers cannot hold arbitrary large number.

Comment: actually in my ref, it provides a solution to train model for addition (make number as a digit sequence). your method whatever classification or regression is merely able to memorize ([a, b] => c), for example, giving [23, 32] then getting 55. when the data set is infinite, a new number maybe [12345678901234567890, 12345678901234567891] will make your model fail. and computer can hold arbitary large number in string.

Comment: Again, why should it fail for large numbers? Check the formula, sum(input) will work all the same for the given example, any set of integers you throw at it. Can you provide a proof that it will fail, instead of just saying it? Math (presented formula) says it will work. Also, "Arbitrary large" means I can think of a string that exceeds memory of any computer.